# NuGet MonoGame WindowsPhone 8.0

Tags: windows-phone-8, xamarin, xna, monogame

I have a problem integrating MonoGame into an existing WindowsPhone8.0 project.
Everything seems to work fine, but when is start the app it's crashing with NullPointerException in MonoGame Framework.

StackTrace:

> at MonoGame.Framework.WindowsPhone.WindowsPhoneGameWindow..ctor(Game game)
>        at MonoGame.Framework.WindowsPhone.WindowsPhoneGamePlatform..ctor(Game game)
>        at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamePlatform.PlatformCreate(Game game)
>        at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game..ctor()
>        at myApp.Game1..ctor()
>        at myApp.myPage..ctor()

EDIT:
I have also tried that: [link](http://darkgenesis.zenithmoon.com/monogame-using-libraries-with-windows-phone-projects/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the stack trace your `myPage` constructor goes somewhat like this:

```
_game = new Game1();
```

The Windows Phone project template, however, does it this way:

```
_game = XamlGame<Game1>.Create("", this);
```

The latter version does lots of initialization, for example stores a reference to the XAML page for framework use. The first version crashes because the said initialization is not done, and tries to access `null` page.

Comment: But now i can not start the game. It crashes when i call "Run()"-Method. NullPointerException    at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.UpdateDevice(Device device, DeviceContext context)

Comment: The template does not call `Run()` at all. I'm not able to verify it right now, but does the game start without the call?